# How get arrays of div texts?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I try to get all texts in divs on the page :

```
<div class="someclass">thistext</div>
```

This is my code:

```
var lnks = [];
function getLinks() {
lnks = document.querySelectorAll('.someclass');
return Array.prototype.map.call(lnks, function(e) {
    return e.fetchText(lnks);
});
}
casper.then(function() {
var lnkss = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});
casper.then(function() {
 for(var i in lnkss) {
    console.log(lnkss[i]);
}
casper.done();
});

casper.run();
```

but it returns nothing. What do I wrong?

Comment: Have not tried `casperjs` though `lnkss` is only defined locally at first `.then()`. `casper.then(function() {
  return this.evaluate(getLinks);
})
.then(function(l) {
 for(var i in l) {
    console.log(l[i]);
})`. Also not sure if `getLinks` actually needs to be called `return this.evaluate(getLinks());`?

Comment: What is `e.fetchText(lnks)` supposed to do? This looks wrong (invoking a member function and handing over the entire HTML collection). You are in the context of a single HTML element, so `return e.innerHTML` should work fine (to get it's content).

Answer (score 1):

I've never used casper, but jumping through some of the documentation for the functions you've used it seems you might be invoking fetchText() in a scope where it isn't defined.

[evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)() says "everytime you pass a closure to evaluate(), you’re entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console."

so try changing

```
return e.fetchText(lnks);
```

to

```
return e.innerHTML;
```

and see what that does for you.

Comment: I change return e.fetchText(lnks); to return e.innerHTML; but it is change nothing

Comment: After having made that change, if you load the page and invoke getLinks() directly from the console, what is your output?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you. This will make a array of DIVs text.

```js
var arr = [];

function makeDivTextArray() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    arr.push(divs[i].innerHTML);
  }
}

makeDivTextArray();

for(var i in arr) {
  document.write(arr[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2</div>
<div>text3</div>
<div>text4</div>
<div>text5</div>
<div>text6</div>
<div>text7</div>
<br/>
```